# Change block scope to an object to save on writing the object's name

Tags: c#, scope, inference

Is there a way to call members within an object's scope?
For example, instead of this:

```
myObject.Foo();
myObject.value = 0;
```

To call within the scope of myObject:

```
myObject.
{
    Foo();
    value = 0;
}
```

This would only serve to save on typing like the implicit type `var` does. It seems possible since at compile time it's known of what type myObject is.

Comment: I really think auto-complete of any modern IDE will defeat the goal and the former snippet is much more readable. And I am not even touching the fact that the latter snippet is not valid C#.

Comment: In VB however, you can use [With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement). But the question is about C#, where I am not aware of an existing equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such syntax available in C#, other than in a call to a constructor, when creating a new instance of the object, you can assign to its public properties.

For example:

```
var obj = new MyObject {
    Value1 = 0;
    Value2 = 1;
    ....
}
```